# Maclaurin of $\ln(\cos2x)$ with standard series.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I want to calculate $\ln(\cos(2x))$ with the standard series to order $4$, but something is wrong.

*Here is what I got:*
First I approximate $\cos(2x)$ as follows: $\cos x = 1 - x^2/2 + x^4/4!$ (and so on), and therefore

$$\cos(2x) = 1 - 2x^2 + \frac{16x^4}{24} + O(x^6) $$

Then I proceed to plug my aproximation of $\cos(2x)$ into the natural logarithm and approximate as follows: $$\ln(1 + x) = x - x^2/2 + O(x^3).$$

$$ln(1 - 2x^2 + (16x^4)/24 + O(x^6)) = 
-2x^2 + (16x^4)/24 + O(x^6)  -  (-2x^2 + 16x^4/24 + O(x^6)I ^ 2 / 2$$

After I get the following: $$-2x^2 + 8x^4 / 3 + O(x^6),$$

wich is incorrect. It is suposed to be: $-2x^2 + 4x^4 / 3 + O(x^6)$.

Comment: Why do you stop the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ to order $2$, if you want order $4$?

Comment: Because of the values plugged into ln, since cos contains x2 and x4, the ln expansion is going to go past x^4 faster than the order 4 for ln

Comment: Use the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ to order $4$ and you'll see why you are wrong in doing what you did. Perhaps you might even understand what you should do in general.

Comment: But does not all values greater then x^6 get collected in O(x^6)?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3760715/568204). If that still doesn't help, then I suggest you write down neatly on a piece of paper two calculations, one where you truncate $\ln(1+x)$ to order $2$ and one where you truncate $\ln(1+x)$ to order $4$ and compare the calculations line by line. Then, you'll surely find the mistake, and understand why we cannot stop earlier.

Comment: You guys are correct, I stand corrected. Thanks for the help, everything worked out just as I wanted. Thanks again!!

Comment: The correct answer is not $-2x^2 + 4x^4 / 3 + O(x^6)$, but $-2x^2 \color{red}{-} 4x^4 / 3 + O(x^6)$

Answer (score 1):

how about this:
$$
f(x)=\ln\cos(2x)\\
f'(x)=2\tan(2x)$$
etc
remembering that:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$
you could use the fact that the derivatives of $\tan(x)$ evaluated at $0$ are well known

---

The problem with your method is it involves taking the series for $\cos$ first, so you have the $\log$ of an infinite series

Comment: There's is no problem with his method, it's perfectly valid to use one asymptotic approximation inside another like this, just need to be done right.